# Speech synthesis: How mark a usual saying as idiom

Tags: c#, .net, text-to-speech, phrase, ssml

There are a couple of idioms or phrases or popular colloquial sayings like „Oh my dear!“ , „Be careful“, „please wait“ or (German)„Ach so!“ or „Achtung“. How can I mark these as special expressions so that the speech synthesis pronounces the phrases in a natural way?

Pseudo code:
`<say-as thing-I-search>Attention please!</say-as>`

Answer (score 1):

In SSML you have the emphasis tag. This can have the values  strong/reduced/moderate. One other option could be to work with voices with a specific style

This is an example of the emphasis tag

```
<speak version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:lang="string">
<voice  name="en-US-GuyNeural">
I say it one more time: 
<emphasis  level="strong">
don't do it again!
</emphasis>
</voice>
</speak>
```

This is an example of the style tag

```
<speak version='1.0' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' xml:lang='en-US' xmlns:mstts = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/mstts'> 
<voice name = 'en-US-JennyNeural'>
I say it one more time: 
<mstts:express-as style='shouting'>
Don't do this a second time or I'll punish you
</mstts:express-as>
</voice>
</speak>
```